# Duplicate points along NURBS curve

Tags: c++, 3d, nurbs

in my current project I have implemented NURBS curves and at the beginning of the curve I have some 3D points, which are all located in the normal plane of the point (u = 0.0). Now I want to copy these points to other locations of the curve (e.g. u = 0.5) to create some kind of extrude / sweep mechanism. My theoretical approach is to create a local coordinate system in point 0.0 and to calculate the coordinates of every point in relation to this system. Then I can create local coordinate systems at the desired points and place the points there. My problem is that with the first derivation of the NURBS curve I can get the tangent and therefore the normal plane of the point / system (local X direction) but I don't know how to orient the system. My first idea was to take the second derivative of the NURBS curve and use this to calculate the local Y and Z axis of the system but the results of the second derivatives does not seem to be suitable for this approach.

Is there a common approach to solve this problem?

As an additional question I am wondering how to dictate the tangent vector of a given control point, for example the tangent of the first control point. Currently I solve this by dictating the position of the second control point, which seems to be not very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the same problem using this approach:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Computation-of-rotation-minimizing-frames.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Look like you would like to find a local coordinate system at any given point on the NURBS curve. If this is the case, Frenet frame is the typical choice. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) for more details.

As for the issue of "tangent vector of a given control point", since control points in general do not lie on the NURBS curve, it does not have a tangent vector. If you really need one for some special reason, you can use the tangent vector at the point on the curve that is closest to the control point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with the Frenet frame is, if I have for example an S-shaped NURBS curve, then the normal vectors at the beginning point in the "upward" direction, the normal vectors at the end point in the "downward" direction. Since I want to copy my points from the beginning to the end I want them not to rotate by 180 degree. But to define normal vectors in one global direction is also not the solution I want to realize, since they should follow the curve shape. I hope it is clear which kind of behaviour I desire.